# How can I Schedule data imports in Solr

Tags: solr

The wiki page, http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler explains how to index data using DataImportHandler. But the example uses a command to initiate the import operation. How can I schedule a job to do this on a regular basis?c

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On UNIX/Linux, [cron jobs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) are your friends! On Windows, there is [Task Scheduler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task_Scheduler).

**UPDATE**
To do it from Java code, since this is a simple GET request, you can use the [HTTP Client](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) library. See [this tutorial](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/tutorial.html) on using the GetMethod.

If you need to programmatically send other requests to Solr, you probably should use the [Solrj library](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolJava). It allows to send all the basic commands to Solr ant it can be configured to access any Solr handlers:

```
CommonsHttpSolrServer server = new CommonsHttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8983/solr");
ModifiableSolrParams params = new ModifiableSolrParams();
params.set("command", "full-import");
QueryRequest request = new QueryRequest(params);
request.setPath("/dataimport");
server.request(request);
```

Comment: Thanks Pascal. My question was different. I need to fire the command http://<host>:<port>/solr/dataimport?command=full-import for the indexing operation. How can I do that using a java class? (as against typing in the command in a browser window?)

Comment: Also, if you are doing it from cron, a wget http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/dataimport?command=full-import works great!

Answer (score 7):

I was able to make it work following the steps:

1. Create classes ApplicationListener, HTTPPostScheduler and SolrDataImportProperties (source code listed on http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Scheduling).
   I believe these classes haven't been committed yet.
2. Add the following listener to Solr web.xml file:

   ```
   <listener>
      <listener-class>org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.scheduler.ApplicationListener</listener-class>
   </listener>
   ```
3. Configure dataimport.properties as per instructions in the wiki page.

Answer (score 7):

simple add this line to your crontab with `crontab -e` command:

```
0,30 * * * * /usr/bin/wget http://<solr_host>:8983/solr/<core_name>/dataimport?command=full-import
```

This will full import every 30 minutes. Replace `<solr_host>` and `<core_name>` with your configuration

Answer (score 1):

There's a fresh patch by Esteve Fernandez that makes the whole thing work on Unix/Linux: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2305

@Eldo If you're going to need more help in building your own JAR just drop a question here...

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit old, but I created a Windows WPF application and service to deal with this, as using CRON jobs and Task Scheduler is a bit difficult to maintain if you have a lot of cores / environments.

https://github.com/systemidx/SolrScheduler

You basically just drop in a JSON file in a specified folder and it will use a REST client to issue the commands to Solr.

Answer (score 1):

We can use Quartz to do that, which is like the crontab on linux. But basically, the TimerTask embedded in jdk is enough for you.