# How to setup DIH scheduler on Solr 5.1.0

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler, dih, solr5

[The wiki page](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler) explains how to setup scheduling in older version of Solr but it hasn't been updated for Solr 5.1.0. The problem is I can't configure the *dataimport.properties* file.

The instructions in the wiki:

> regardless of whether you have single or multiple-core Solr, use
>   *dataimport.properties* located in your solr.home/conf (NOT solr.home/core/conf)

In Solr 5.1 there is no *dataimport.properties* located in solr.home/conf, and it doesn't work if I use the one in the core.

Is there any way I can get this to work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [DIH Scheduling in Solr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432190/dih-scheduling-in-solr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have similar problem in my application.I have setup separate application to schedule delta/full-import.Wiki page you mentioned is not committed to Solr code base.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. I created a powershell script that get called by the event scheduler in Windows Server.

Here's a what I used to do a full data import : 

$url="http://localhost:8984/solr/fichierJoints/dataimport?command=full-import"
(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString("$url");

Comment: Yes!correct.I did this with the help of java application