# SOLR DIH Scheduler Not Working

Tags: solr, scheduler, dih

I have set solr scheduler properties in **dataimport.properties** file to update the index as described at

```
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#dataimport.properties_example
```

with interval = 1, But after that i created new record in my table and searched again the same keyword but niether new record is not coming up in the result nor total record count is increased by one record.

Am i missing anything

Comment: Sorry for being basic, but you **do** mean that you did a q=* and saw that the document is not indexed, right?

Comment: All i just want to update my document indexed automatically by using scheduler. I dont want to write a cron (as i using solr in php) to update my document. I set the interval =1 so that if i make any change in database, document will be reflected after each minute.

Comment: My document is being indexed and working fine but i want to make update of document automatically on each minute.

Answer (score 1):

Did you apply the patches? As described in the wiki, scheduling features are not a part of standard Solr, you have to include the code in the wiki. Adding settings to the properties file without it will have no effect.

Comment: All i did, just made changes in dataimport.properties file as described in wiki but set interval=1. I don't see any way suggested by wiki to apply patches? Can you please provide any example code or steps to add patches. Were you able to configure scheduler successfully?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206171/how-can-i-schedule-data-imports-in-solr