# Auto Indexing in Solr

Tags: solr, cron, indexing, dataimporthandler, solr4

Hi Im using Solr 4's Data Import Utility to index Oracle 10g XE database. 
Im using full imports as well as delta imports. I want these processes to be automatic. (Eg: The import processes can be timed or should be executed as soon any data in the database is modified).
 I searched for the same online and I heard people talk about CRON and scripts. However, Im not able to figure out how to implement it. Can you please provide a tutorial like explanation?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this previous question: [How can I schedule data imports in Solr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206171/how-can-i-schedule-data-imports-in-solr) or as an alternative you could consider building and using the DataImportScheduler outlined in the [Scheduling section of the DataImportHandler page on Solr Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Scheduling)

Answer (score 0):

Cron scheduler with wget command can be used to automate data import process. In latest solr version "**?command=**" parameter not works with get method, so used post method as below

```
wget http://server-url:port/solr/collection-name/dataimport" --post-data 'command=full-import&clean=true&commit=true&wt=json&indent=true&verbose=false&optimize=false&debug=false'
```

As cron job can be execute minimum 1 minute's interval, If you would like to execute less than a minute, you can prepare a bash script with infinite loop.

```
#!/bin/bash

while true 
do
    wget "http://server-url:port/solr/collection-name/dataimport" --post-data 'command=full-import&clean=true&commit=true&wt=json&indent=true&verbose=false&optimize=false&debug=false' &> /dev/null
    sleep 5
done
```