# How to configure Solr for indexing once a day

Tags: apache, solr, lucene

I'm a newbie with Solr, I use it for indexing and search files on a server through a webservice.

I would know how to configure it to run the indexing process only once a day (for example at 3:00am).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I Schedule data imports in Solr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206171/how-can-i-schedule-data-imports-in-solr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are calling it through the web service, add/write a scheduler which will invoke the web service at the required time.

For writing the scheduler please refer below links

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-run-a-task-periodically-in-java/

http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/a/java/archive/quartz.html

Comment: Thanks for reply. I hopped there's another solution but it seems that's the only one...