# Is data importing automatic in solr?

Tags: solr

I'm using Solr 4.10.4 with MySQL on Windows.

Solr recommends setting the HTTP cache setting `max-age` to half of how often the index gets updated update the index.

So, the question is: **does Solr automatically perform full/delta imports?** If so, how do I control that?
If not, I assume it's up to me to update the index regularly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Howie
SOLR can be configured to pull data using a DataImportHandler
You should look at this documentation for details https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler

There is some documentation on scheduling the data pull but it appears that its not a configurable feature and requires some additional changes. The section http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Scheduling discuss the same. Also there is a Stackoverflow question on the same [How can I Schedule data imports in Solr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206171/how-can-i-schedule-data-imports-in-solr)

Alternately you can also post data to SOLR as needed from your System. 
Both strategies will work. It depends completely on what is better for your system. I would recommend going through the appropriate docs on Indexing https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FrontPage#Search_and_Indexing and then decide which strategy works better for your application

Comment: Could you point me to the right direction about `actively pull data using a DIH`? Are you talking about the `Scheduling` section?

Comment: @Howie I revisited my answer and the docs and it appears that 'actively' pull data is not possible as yet. But the docs still point in direction of how often to trigger the pull request. I have modified my answer to add info around that. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. I needed some confirmation about this.